# Fine Tuning hyperparameters doesn't improve score of classifiers

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, dataset

I am experiencing a problem where finetuning the hyperparameters using GridSearchCV doesn't really improve my classifiers. I figured the improvement should be bigger than that. The biggest improvement for a classifier I've gotten with my current code is around +-0.03. I have a dataset with eight columns and an unbalanced binary outcome. For scoring I use f1 and I use KFold with 10 splits. I was hoping if someone could spot something which is off and I should look at? Thank you!

I use the following code:

```
model_parameters = {
    "GaussianNB": {     
    },
    "DecisionTreeClassifier": {
        'min_samples_leaf': range(5, 9),
        'max_depth': [None, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    },
    "KNeighborsClassifier": {
        'n_neighbors': range(1, 10),
        'weights': ["distance", "uniform"]
    },
    "SVM": {
        'kernel': ["poly"],
        'C': np.linspace(0, 15, 30)
    },
    "LogisticRegression": {
        'C': np.linspace(0, 15, 30),
        'penalty': ["l1", "l2", "elasticnet", "none"]
    }
}

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.4)
n_splits = 10
scoring_method = make_scorer(lambda true_target, prediction: f1_score(true_target, prediction, average="micro"))
cv = KFold(n_splits=n_splits, random_state=random_state, shuffle=True)

for model_name, parameters in model_parameters.items():

    # Models is a dict with 5 classifiers
    model = models[model_name]
    grid_search = GridSearchCV(model, parameters, cv=cv, n_jobs=-1, scoring=scoring_method, verbose=False).fit(X_train, y_train)
    
    cvScore = cross_val_score(grid_search.best_estimator_, X_test, y_test, cv=cv, scoring='f1').mean()
    classDict[model_name] = cvScore
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your classes are unbalanced, when you do Kfold you should keep the proportion between the two targets.

Having folds unbalanced can lead to very poor results

check [Stratified K-Folds cross-validator](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html)

> Provides train/test indices to split data in train/test sets.
>
> This cross-validation object is a variation of KFold that returns
> stratified folds. The folds are made by preserving the percentage of
> samples for each class.

There are also a lot of techniques to handle unbalanced dataset. Based on the context:

- upsampling the minority class (using for example the [resample from sklearn](https://elitedatascience.com/imbalanced-classes))
- under sampling the majority class (also this [lib](https://pypi.org/project/imbalanced-learn/) has some useful tools to do both under\up sampling)
- handle the unbalance with your specific ML model

For example, in SVC, there is an argument when you create the model , `class_weight='balanced'`

```
clf_3 = SVC(kernel='linear', 
            class_weight='balanced', # penalize
            probability=True)
```

which will penalize more the errors on minority class.

You can change your config as such:

```
"SVM": {
        'kernel': ["poly"],
        'C': np.linspace(0, 15, 30),
        'class_weight': 'balanced'

    }
```

For LogisticRegression you can set the weights instead, reflecting the proportion of your classes

```
LogisticRegression(class_weight={0:1, 1:10}) # if problem is a binary one
```

changing the grid search dict in such way:

```
"LogisticRegression": {
        'C': np.linspace(0, 15, 30),
        'penalty': ["l1", "l2", "elasticnet", "none"],
        'class_weight':{0:1, 1:10}
    }
```

Anyway the approach depends on the used model. For neural network for example, you can change the loss function to penalize the minority class with a weighted calculation (the same of the logistic regression)