# Too low sensitivity

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, confusion-matrix

I am dealing with logistic regression analysis. While the number of patients with a target value of 0 in the data was 2000, the number of patients with 1 was 188. Although the total accuracy was 92, the sensitivity was extremely low. Could this be because of the unbalanced class? the results are like this:

**Scores:**

```
test score: 0.90
train score: 0.92
```

**Confusion matrix:**

```
TRUE POSITIVE:  498
FALSE POSITIVE:  47
TRUE NEGATIVE:  2
FALSE NEGATIVE:  3
```

**Some metrics:**

```
Overall Accuracy: 0.90
Sensitivity:  0.99
Specificity: 0.040

False Positive Rate:  0.959
False Discovery Rate:  0.086
Positive Predictive Value:  0.91
Negative Predictive Value:  0.4

F1 score:  0.952
Roc Auc: 0.822
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory & methodology.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is due to an unbalance in your classes.

Due to the imbalance, your model *prefers* to predict positive almost for every instance, because it's easier for the model to do so.

To handle this problem there are a lot of strategies, for example:

- if you do cross-validation to evaluate your model, make stratified folds
- you can try to under sample your majority class
- you can try to up sample your minority class (there are a lot of generative approaches to generate new data from minority class: [if you use python](https://pypi.org/project/imbalanced-learn/))
- change your model parameters. With LogistRegression you can usually give weights to your classes, to penalize with great error the minority class. The implementations depends on what language you use

In `scikit-learn` you would do something like this:

```
LogisticRegression(class_weight={0:1, 1:10})
```

In the above example I am giving to the class '1' an error 10 times greater than the errors for the class '0'.

**Note:** This weights are an hyperparameter of your model, and therefore should be validated.

Anyway, if you want a more extensive answer, check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64542349/fine-tuning-hyperparameters-doesnt-improve-score-of-classifiers/64543008#64543008)

Comment: than you very much.  "model=LogisticRegression(C=0.1,class_weight={0:1,1:10},max_iter=10000)" solved my problem.

Comment: @Muratışıkalan you're welcome. Don't forget to accept the best answer :)